# AngularFire get and set a single value from/to a firebase database

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

My firebase database is called verhuurfietsen and I have a maximum amount of 4 which I want to get and set but still the maximum has to be 4.

[image: firebase]

```
 obj;
 constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase){}
 ngOnInit() {
  this.obj = this.db.database.ref('amount');
 }

 updateMaxValue(){
  this.obj.update(this.max)
 }
```

pushing is not an issue but I can't seem to find anywhere how you get a single value out of a firebase database. I want to initialise my `max` variable with the valure from the firebase db

Comment: What you mean by "still the maximum has to be 4". when you update that value going to change for sure.

Comment: Well the max amount is 4 so in my code I will make it so that it can never go higher than 4 put still I want to get this value and I only see list and object but not a simple way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try in Angularfire2 way

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.db.object('amount').valueChanges().subscribe(action => {
      console.log(action);
      for(var obj in action) { 
          console.log(obj); 
          this.max = Number.parseInt(obj);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. :)

Comment: TS2399: Property 'val' does not exist on type '{}'. the val() does not exist?

Comment: what you get when you do `console.log(action)`

Comment: a 4 but it's a {} not a number is there a way to parse or convert it?

Comment: is it displaying like `{"amount":4}`  or just {4}

Comment: just `4` xD but when i try to put it in my `this.max` which is a `number` it says `Type '{}' is not assignable to number`

Comment: I thinks data coming as Object. Try a for loop to get that data.

Comment: this works: `this.db.object('amount').valueChanges().subscribe(action => {
      console.log(action);
      for(let obj in action) {
        console.log(obj);
        this.max = Number.parseInt(obj);
      }
    });`